# Dataflow streaming job processes the same element many times at the same time

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Short description:
Dataflow is processing the same input element many times, even at the same time in parallel (so this is not fail-retry build-in mechanism of dataflow, because previous process didn't fail).

Long description:
Pipeline gets pubsub message in which path to GCS file is stored.
In next step (DoFn class) this file is open and read line by line, so sometimes for very big files this is long process and takes up to 1 hour (per file).

Many times (very often) those big files are processing at the same time.
I see it based on logs messages, that first process loads already 500k rows, another one 300k rows and third one just started, all of them are related to the same file and all of them based on the same pubsub message (the same message_id).

Also pubsub queue chart is ugly, those messages are not acked so unacked chart does not decrease.

Any idea what is going on? Have you experienced something similar?

I want to underline that this is not a issue related to fail and retry process.
If first process fails and second one started for the same file - that is fine and expected.
Unexpected is, if those two processes lives at the same time.

Comment: How are you acking the pubsub msg? in dataflow? Is pubsub redelivering the msg after it is not acked within the pipeline?

Comment: @SakshiGatyan dataflow is responsible for a acking pubsub. I think this is pubsub redelivers it. If file is processed long time, dataflow sends to pubsub request to modify pubsub ack deadline. Not sure why even so pubsub redeliver those messages over and over again

Answer (score 1):

When a file is added on `Cloud storage` and fire an automatic notification to `Pub Sub`, multiple notifications can be sent :

```
- OBJECT_FINALIZE   Sent when a new object (or a new generation of an existing object) is successfully created in the bucket. This includes copying or rewriting an existing object. A failed upload does not trigger this event.
- OBJECT_METADATA_UPDATE    Sent when the metadata of an existing object changes.
...
```

[pubsub-notifications doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications)

You can access to the `attributes` of the `PubSubMessage` in `Beam` and filter only messages with attribute `event type` and `OBJECT_FINALIZE` value.

In this case, only one message per file will be treaten by your `Dataflow` job and then the `DoFn` will open this file and treat elements only once.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If this was a case, pubsub `message_id` would be different, but are the same

Answer (score 1):

Here is a likely possibility:

- reading the file is being "fused" with reading the message from Cloud Pubsub, so that the hour of processing happens before the result is saved to Dataflow's internal storage and the message can be ACKed
- since your processing is so long, Cloud Pubsub will deliver the message again
- there is no way that Dataflow cancel's your DoFn processing, so you will see them both processing at the same time, even though one of them is expired and will be rejected when processing is complete

What you really want is for the large file reads to be split and parallelized. Beam can do this easily (and currently I believe is the only framework that can). You pass the filenames to `TextIO.readFiles()` transform and the reading of each large file will be split and performed in parallel, and there will be enough checkpointing that the pubsub message will be ACKed before it expires.

<s>One thing you might try is to put a `Reshuffle` in between the `PubsubIO.read()` and your processing.</s>

Comment: Thanks for the anawer! Very interesting. Dataflow has this mechanizm you mentioned that process is expired becsuse pubsub has been redeliverd and process Goes to the end but after that it is Just droped? And Yes, i have fused Reading step with validation step

Comment: Actually I am going to add a better answer. You really want to split the processing of those large files, and Beam has this ability using "splittable DoFn". We already provide what you need in the `TextIO.readFiles` transform.

Comment: Ah I see you are using Python. I am not sure if this exists for the Python SDK directly. Beam also allows easy use of transforms from any SDK in all the other SDKs, with a little boilerplate. I am asking around what the best way for you to do this is.

Comment: This does exist for the Python SDK - I will get the best link to what you should use and update the answer shortly.